# Proof of definite integral

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Let $f$ be a continuous function. Without taking an anti-derivative, prove that $$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt=0$$

Comment: Isn't this the definition?

Comment: Can you assume that integral is a continuous function of the upper limit?Because if you can this is trivial. You better tell us *what* can we assume and what not...and **why** are you trying to solve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the below approach is using mean-value theorem for integrals. An alternative is to use the fact that $f$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval  $[0,a]$. Then we have that;

$$\int_{[0,a]} f \leq \left[|\textrm{max}(f)| \cdot a \right]\to 0,\ \textrm{as}\  a \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

There exists $c_a\in [0,a]$ such that $\int_0^af(t)dt=af(c_a)$. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, there exists $c>0, M>0$, such that for every $x\in [-c,c]. |f(x)|<M$.
For $a\in [-c,c]$, $|\int_0^af(t)dt|\leq |af(c_a)|\leq |a|M$. This implies that $|lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\int_0^af(t)dt|\leq lim_{a\rightarrow 0}M|a|=0$.